# Is $f'(a)\ge0$ or $f'(a)>0$

Tags: derivatives

> If $f$ is smooth s.t. $f<0$ on $(0,a)$ and $f>0$ on $(a,1)$ is then $f'(a)\ge0$ or $f'(a)>0$ ?

Is it possible that $f'(a)=0$, maybe you have an example ?

Comment: Try $f(x)=(x-a)^3$

Comment: I think it's funny how almost everybody (me included) thought of the same thing.

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando except me

Comment: Oh well. Getting a piece of paper and drawing stuff usually helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple example :
$f:x\to (x-a)^3$